# Selenium Python try to iterate thru a dropdown paginator by can't get select_by_index working

Tags: python, selenium, pagination

I'm using selenium in python trying to iterate thru a dropdown paginator. Got stuck on select_by_index and digged Stackoverflow for an answer without luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('start-maximized')    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = '/mnt/d/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options = options)
driver.get("http://exhibitors.jewellerynetasia.com/shenzhen2017/en/")


element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text() ="1"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
element.click()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="Paging1"]'))

for index in range(1, len(select.options)):
    print(index)
    select.select_by_index(index)
```

The error message:

File "pagitest.py", line 42, in 
    select.select_by_index(index)

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: 
        Message: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and 
        may not be manipulated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your dropdown is a CSS dropdown, not a HTML native dropdown(which purly  composed by select and option tag),

Even your dropdown also includes select and option tag, but they are invisble(you can find `display: none;` in its style attribute), so your dropdown is no way be controled by the invisible select and option tag.

**To operate CSS dropdown, you can't use the `Select` class** which is only suite for native dropdown,  you have to operate as you did manually:

**Click it to expand all options -> Click on option**

```
// There are two similar dropdown, only one visible
dropdown_wrapper = driver
    .find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='page_dm'][not(contains(@style, 'none'))]");

// click wrapper to expand options to display
dropdown_wrapper
    .find_element_by_css_selector("p.SelectBox").click()

// find out all options
options = dropdown_wrapper
    .find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.options > li")


for index in range(1, len(options)):
    print(index)

    // click option
    options[index].click()

    // find all options again to avoid StaleElementReferenceException
    // because each page number change, the page content changed
    options = dropdown_wrapper
        .find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.options > li")
```

Comment: Many thanks Yong, your answer is enlightening and very helpful.